# Cannot identify image using browser.Images.Filter(Find.By("ext:qtip", "Delete")).Click()

Tags: c#, watin

I want to Click image : following is the html code

I am using following code in watin to click :

```
browser.Image(Find.By("ext:qtip", "Delete").Click();
```

It is not working. Please let me know other way.

```
<div class="x-panel x-column" id="delete-button-2-7qo0yziAwqKk02Gud0Ik" style="width: 12px; padding-top: 2px; padding-left: 8px;">
    <div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen580">
        <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" id="ext-gen581" style="width: 12px;">
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                <img style="width: 16px;" src="/image/poll-grey-close.png" ext:qtip="Delete"/>
```

Comment: I am using IE9 for my testing.

Answer (score 1):

This not working because ":" is reserved css selector char try to search using css selector like this:

```
browser.Image(Find.BySelector("img[ext\\:qtip=\"Delete\"]")).Click();
```

I didn't checked this code so maybe fine tuning needed...

Comment: Thank you for the suggested answer.No it is not working.

On the other hand when I installed IE 8 browser.Image(Find.By("ext:qtip", "Delete").Click(); is working fine. But on IE9 it is not working.